# Saving a "CHECK" checkbox state on starting app

Tags: java, android, checkbox, state

Hi I got a problem with "saving status of my checkbox". In my case: check status- enables sounds, uncheck status - disables them. On my options.xml I got set up:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/bbutton_sound"
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
android:text="@string/ebsound"    
android:layout_marginTop="20.00dp"    
android:checked="true"/>
```

Problem is that when I uncheck the checbox in options. After exiting the app and entering it again all sounds are enabled (which is correct) but checkbox stays unchecked (which should get back to the check state). I don't know how to achive this. I tried to force on "check state" by ondestroy method but nothing helps. Here is my java code:

```
package com.Pong;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Options extends Activity {
  private CheckBox bbutton_sound;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);
    addListenerOnButton();
    bbutton_sound.setChecked(true);
    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.menu_button_sound);
    Button BackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Back);
    BackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent MenuIntent = new Intent(Options.this,Menu.class);
            Options.this.finish();
            startActivity(MenuIntent);
            mpButtonClick.start();
        }
    });

  }
  @Override
  public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      save(bbutton_sound.isChecked());

  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      bbutton_sound.setChecked(load());
  }

  private void save(final boolean isChecked) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("check", isChecked);
      editor.commit();
  }

  private boolean load() { 
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check", true);
  }

  public void addListenerOnButton() {
      bbutton_sound = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bbutton_sound);
      bbutton_sound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            AudioManager volumeControl = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeControl.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
            int maxVolume = volumeControl.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            volumeControl.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, maxVolume);

            Toast.makeText(Options.this,
               "Sounds enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()==(false)){
            AudioManager volumeControl = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeControl.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
            Toast.makeText(Options.this,
                       "Sounds disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      } 
    });

  }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: i think your check box is unchecked because it was his last state which you saved in SharedPreferences so the code works fine. maybe you should extend the Application class and set your property saved in SharedPreferences to true or just remove it in Application.onCreate() method. After that every time your app will be launched your button should have been checked.

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry for late reply but i found a way to remove that unwanted check :). This is kind of cheaty because all I had to do was to remove that state in onCreate method on IntroGame activity which is the first activity in my game and can not be skipped :).

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.remove("check");
    editor.commit();
```

Thank you for your help and interest!

Answer (score 0):

When you back your settings are saved so when you start the application it takes the value unchecked.

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.remove("check");
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Wow this works but as You can see I got back button which leads me in to the main menu. That automaticly finishes options activity and starts the menu one. "Options" is a part of menu activity when I set onDestroy() method in Options activity and leave box unchecked, next time I enter options (without quiting) I will get box checked. What I am thinking is that my app contains "splash screen" activity which is before menu. If I colud make your onDestroy method on that activity it would work just fine, but how can I make a reference?

Comment: Replace editor.remove("check"); for editor.putBoolean("check", true); in onDestroy and take a look!

Comment: That doesn't work as well. Same effect that I mentioned above. I also tried to call "putBoolean("check", true);" in my splash screen activity, but nothing even happens or I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: Remove bbutton_sound.setChecked(true); and the onDestroy() method. Test now!

Answer (score 0):

Your Options/Menu setup might be easier to use and debug if you use the built-in Preferences XML+Activity/Fragment framework. You can just use a pre-built CheckBoxPreference and it will always get its checked state from the associated saved preference. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

In res/xml:

```
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="@string/pref_sounds_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_sounds_title"
        android:summary="@string/pref_sounds_summary"
        android:persistent="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:defaultValue="false"
    />
```

In your Activity:

```
public boolean getPreferenceSounds() {
    String key = getString (R.string.pref_sounds_key);
    boolean result = getSharedPreferences().getBoolean (key, false);

    return result;
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, 
    String key) { ... }
```

Comment: Also noticed you're using onClickListener(View) for your CheckBox - if you're going that route, better to use [onCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton,boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html).